# Extrapolating/forecasting treatment effects from difference-in-difference model

Tags: r, predictive-models, forecasting, causality

My goal is to extrapolate or forecast dynamic treatment effects into the future using a fitted model. My data consists of two groups (treated and control), seven time points, and a continuous outcome.

```
library(tibble)

set.seed(535)

d <- tibble(id = rep(1:10, each = 7),
            periods = factor(rep(0:6, times = 10)),
            treated = factor(ifelse(id<=5, 1, 0)),
            y = ifelse(treated==1, rnorm(100, 2, 0.5), rnorm(100, 0, 1)))

head(d, n=10)
# A tibble: 10 × 4
      id periods treated     y
   <int> <fct>   <fct>   <dbl>
 1     1 0       1        1.32
 2     1 1       1        3.15
 3     1 2       1        2.06
 4     1 3       1        1.78
 5     1 4       1        2.26
 6     1 5       1        2.02
 7     1 6       1        2.38
 8     2 0       1        1.93
 9     2 1       1        1.72
10     2 2       1        2.45
```

To fit the model, I used a standard two-way fixed-effects DiD approach where there are fixed effects for time (`periods` in my case) and group (`treated` in my case), and the treatment effect is represented by the interaction of the two (`treated`*`periods`). The fitted model output is below:

```
# fit model
m <- lm(y ~ treated*periods, data = d)

# print model output
broom::tidy(m, conf.int = TRUE)

# A tibble: 14 × 7
   term              estimate std.error statistic   p.value conf.low conf.high
   <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 (Intercept)         -0.699     0.412    -1.69  0.0958      -1.52      0.128
 2 treated1             2.54      0.583     4.35  0.0000588    1.37      3.70 
 3 periods1             0.699     0.583     1.20  0.236       -0.470     1.87 
 4 periods2             0.404     0.583     0.692 0.492       -0.765     1.57 
 5 periods3             0.499     0.583     0.856 0.396       -0.669     1.67 
 6 periods4             1.40      0.583     2.40  0.0199       0.229     2.57 
 7 periods5             0.687     0.583     1.18  0.244       -0.481     1.86 
 8 periods6             1.00      0.583     1.72  0.0913      -0.166     2.17 
 9 treated1:periods1   -0.333     0.825    -0.404 0.688       -1.99      1.32 
10 treated1:periods2   -0.324     0.825    -0.393 0.696       -1.98      1.33 
11 treated1:periods3   -0.405     0.825    -0.491 0.625       -2.06      1.25 
12 treated1:periods4   -0.947     0.825    -1.15  0.256       -2.60      0.706
13 treated1:periods5   -0.496     0.825    -0.601 0.550       -2.15      1.16 
14 treated1:periods6   -0.880     0.825    -1.07  0.291       -2.53      0.772
```

Now, I want to use the `predict` function to forecast/extrapolate future (unobserved) values of `y`.

```
d_preds <- tibble(id = rep(1:10, each = 3),
            periods = factor(rep(7:9, times = 10)),
            treated = factor(ifelse(id<=5, 1, 0)),
            y = NA_real_)

predict(m, newdata = d_preds)
```

However, because the `periods` variable is coded as a factor, the `predict` function produces the following error: `Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : factor periods has new levels 7, 8, 9`.

What are some ways to deal with these issues to accomplish the goal of forecasting treatment effects in this example? Is it as simple as needing to convert the `periods` variable from a factor to numeric?

Comment: With time FE, you have no coefficients for the out-of-sample periods 7,8,9

Comment: Yes, I understand that the coding of time (the `period` variable in my case) as a factor--which is required for fixed-effects estimation--rather than as numeric, is what's causing the problem. I guess my larger question is whether it is possible to somehow obtain forecasts/predictions using a two-way fixed effects type approach at all and, if so, how? My initial thought for how to deal with this problem was to first forecast the panel data using time series forecasting methods and then fit the fixed-effects model to the observed + forecasted data. But that didn't seem like the "right" approach

Comment: You don’t have a model where extrapolating on time makes sense.

Comment: What model would you suggest instead @IRFTM

Comment: The point is that this is not a coding issue to do with factor vs. numeric variables, as your question (esp. the last line) implies. One option is y = b0 +  b1 * D_treat + b2 * D_t + b3 * (f(t) * D_treat) where f(t) could be e.g. linear or quadratic trend. This dummies out the baseline time FEs but parameterises the DiD as a trend. Then the treatment effect is b1 + b3 * f(t). If you want a a prediction of this treatment effect, set the post-sample period dummies to anything, since they net out. All that said, I do slightly shudder at extrapolating the path of treatment effects in this way.